# Python: Opening a file within a print() function

Tags: python, file, printing, buffer, coding-efficiency

I am aware that when you open a file in Python, you must always close it. However, I was wondering what happens if you're not assigning your file to a variable and are only opening it in a print function.

Example: `print(open('file.txt','r').read())`

Is there a way to close a file opened within a function?

Something more pythonic than

```
F=open('file.txt','r')
print(F.read())
F.close()
```

Comment: Trying to do a bunch of stuff in one line is not Pythonic.  Don't try to open the file inside the `print` call.

Comment: Why? That's not "Pythonic" at all, it's just a bad idea and hard to read.

Comment: In Python3.5, you can: print(pathlib.Path('file.txt').read_text())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `with` construct.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

If the file is very large, I suggest iterating over it and printing it a line at a time:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')
```

Of course, if the file is that large, it's probably not useful to print it to an ordinary console, but this practice is very useful for *processing* large files.

Comment: Wait, so this would close it automatically right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. As soon as the `with` block ends, the file is closed, regardless of any errors that may have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

So opening a file like that is not a good idea.

Just use context managers:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: This is much better, thank you